# Can we add other stack exchanges to our “Close Off-Topic” list?

Tags: feature-request, migration

This question
[How much antimatter can we theoretically hold in a Minimum Magnetic Field Trap?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/160416/how-much-antimatter-can-we-theoretically-hold-in-a-minimum-magnetic-field-trap)
should move to Physics SE. But when I vote to close as off-topic, the only migration option is WB Meta. Can moderators add to our set of alternate SEs? Chemistry and Physics and History are the ones I usually want as options.

Comment: If you search for "migrate" you will find at least one excellent explanation from Monica on this subject.

Comment: @L.Dutch I can see that. But I think it is time to fill in the hole. We should not migrate bad questions, but we should migrate good questions that are off-topic.

Comment: @SRM-ReinstateMonica it seems rather unlikely that a question posted *here* would be a *good question* for Physics. Not that questions here are bad but rather the requirements for each stack is different. So, while you *may* have a question which is a good target for migration, I'd expect this to be a rather rare occurrence, so a custom mod flag should suffice. A ready migration path will most likely result in a lot of unsuitable questions being potentially forwarded.

Comment: @VLAZ We don’t have to suspect. I’ve seen multiple over the years.